# How to update a field in SP when other is changed with no particuar value

Tags: workflow

I am creating a long form (more than 100 items!) which is a request tool.  The requester can open a ticket, it can be resolved, and they can come back to re open it. I want 2 fields (status and assigned to) to be cleared out when the ticket is reopened and the Request type is changed. it has several options, and i want it to run regardless of the option that is selected, and only when is changed, not when it it created. Can it be done?

Comment: Hi! Do you use SP Online or On-premise?

Comment: Im using Sharepoint On Premise